# How Do I Send Command Prompt Arguments from a Windows Form Application in C# for .NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, command-line

This one should be an easy one.

An example would be the following:

The user clicks a button titled "Ping" and it uses the command prompt "ping" to ping the server.  The output is captured in a string and displayed in the windows forms app to the user.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to start a new process. You can redirect standard error and output - in this case you probably want to do so in an event-driven manner, to write text to the app when it comes out of ping.

Assuming you want the user to see output as it comes, you *don't* want to use ReadToEnd on the output - that will block until it's finished.

Here's a complete example which writes to the console - but it shows how to do it as the process writes output, rather than waiting for the process to finish:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("ping")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            Arguments = "google.com"
        };
        Process proc = Process.Start(psi);
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

Just for good measure, here's a complete WinForms app:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Button button = new Button {
            Text = "Click me",
            Dock = DockStyle.Top
        };        
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox {
            Multiline = true,
            ReadOnly = true,
            Location = new Point(5, 50),
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };
        Form form = new Form {
            Text = "Pinger",
            Size = new Size(500, 300),
            Controls = { textBox, button }
        };

        Action<string> appendLine = line => {
            MethodInvoker invoker = () => textBox.AppendText(line + "\r\n");
            textBox.BeginInvoke(invoker);
        };

        button.Click += delegate
        {        
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("ping")
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                Arguments = "google.com"
            };
            Process proc = Process.Start(psi);
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => appendLine(e.Data);
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => appendLine(e.Data);
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
            proc.Exited += delegate { appendLine("Done"); };
        };

        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just can't get ahead today...haha.

Answer (score 2):

```
Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ping ...."); 
System.IO.StreamReader reader = p.StandardOutput; 
string sRes = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
reader.Close();
```

The string variable `sRes` should contain the results of the `ping` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string Ping(string url)
{
    Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ping.exe", url);
    StreamReader reader = p.StandardOutput;

    String output = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I covered this pretty extensively on my [blog](http://brianmackey.net/Blog/?p=10).  You can copy paste the fully compileable example.  With only a very basic understanding of Winforms you can fill in the blanks yourself.